# Rails/ActiveRecord - How does creating an object I don't use change the type of another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm new to Ruby and Rails and have inherited a codebase.  My goal with this question in to understand RoR better rather than just to fix this specific bug.

[Just as an unrelated example of the type of thing I'm trying to understand, at one point the code calls `@employee.build_current_employment`.  Grepping shows that `build_current_employment` isn't declared anywhere in the codebase, but the function name indicates that it should be code we've written rather than something from a third-party library (which also makes Google unhelpful).  Eventually I figured out that ActiveRecord is creating function definitions at runtime, based on our own class names, which is the sort of secret handshake garbage I expect is the issue here.]

In our code, app/models contains employee.rb which declares class Employee and time_off_type.rb which declares class TimeOffType, while app/models/employee contains time_off_type.rb which declares class Employee::TimeOffType.  Each of these inherits from ActiveRecord::Base and nothing else.

Class Employee contains

```
has_many :time_off_types, class_name: '::Employee::TimeOffType'
```

while the class TimeOffType in app/models/employee contains

```
belongs_to :employee
belongs_to :company_time_off_type, class_name: '::TimeOffType', foreign_key: 'time_off_type_id'
```

and the other TimeOffType doesn't directly connect to either of them, but it does have

```
belongs_to :company
```

I've added the following function to Employee

```
def assign_time_off_types

  # junk = TimeOffType.new      # Uncommenting this fixes the problem
  # puts junk.class.name        # Outputs Employee::TimeOffType
  # junk = Employee::TimeOffType.new        # Uncommenting this also fixes the problem
  # junk = ::TimeOffType.new    # Uncommenting this doesn't fix the problem
  # junk = nil

  company.time_off_types.each do |i|
    new_time_off_entry = Employee::TimeOffType.create(employee_id: self.id, time_off_type_id: i.id)
#   new_time_off_entry = ::Employee::TimeOffType.create(employee_id: self.id, time_off_type_id: i.id)   # Produces the same error
#   new_time_off_entry = TimeOffType.create(employee_id: self.id, time_off_type_id: i.id)               # Produces the same error
  end
end
```

Calling this function gives me the error `unknown attribute 'employee_id' for TimeOffType.`  However, if I uncomment one of the first two 'junk' lines everything works fine, db entries are created as expected, etc.  It doesn't matter whether I nil junk immediately after creating it, either.

1. Why is new_time_off_entry of type TimeOffType instead of Employee::TimeOffType, despite my explicit request for the latter?
2. How does creating a TimeOffType object fix the problem and why does it default to Employee::TimeOffType?

Edit: As requested

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

class Employee::TimeOffType < ActiveRecord::Base

class TimeOffType < ActiveRecord::Base

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Comment: Can you post the first line class definitions for each of these models? The `class ClassName < Activ...` lines

Comment: "secret handshake garbage" is a really unfortunate way to describe what is known in the Rails world as 'convention over configuration'. Rails provides tons of behavior based upon this idea. It's a pretty central theme in the framework...

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure about leaving that in, but it was such a pain figuring out what was going on there.  Especially since the name it was generating wasn't something I could readily track down.  I can understand needing to know the basics of Ruby and Rails, but this seems to go beyond that.  If you don't already know the conventions, how do you find out about them?

Comment: @Stephen The Rails Guides introduce the conventions. The specific convention you are talking about is explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to. This being said, rails conventions make this easier / faster when you know them, but they definitely make things harder if, as in your case, you are inheriting a project without a rails background. (PS: that guide is for Rails 4.2. There are other guides for other versions of Rails.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely running afoul of a [Constant Autoloading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) problem, due to having two different classes with the same name in different scopes.

Usually a [`require_dependency`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#require-dependency) will sort this out.